# how to directly upload a file to cloud storage from direct download link

Tags: upload

I have to download some files. so I am haveing direct download links for those files. But here is the promblem.. I want to upload directly those files to my direct cloud storage(eg: google drive..etc) without downloading in my pc.

Answer (score 0):

There's a chrome extension that helps:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cloud-save/dlbemabjbfhjcccahjioenmkgimjbbkd/related?hl=en

also you can check:
http://ctrlq.org/